# Content matching from Database and text file using java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, text-files

I have a database in which i have 3 columns (id, name, info_link).

I have the **id** and **names** stored in the database.

I have a text file where i have all the info links scraped.

Info link is in the form of : `http://someURL/**Name**.htm`

Now what I want to do is Take a name from the database, read a line from the text file of links, find if the link(line) contains that drug name, put that link in the info_link column of the record.

This is what my code is

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./Links.txt"));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./AddedLinks.txt"));
int id = 1;
//Creates a connection to the Database
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

statement = connection.createStatement();
for(id=1;id<=1153;)
{   
   query = statement.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM drug_list WHERE id = '"+id+"';");
   query.next();
   String name = query.getString(1);
   String words[] = name.split(" ");
   String Myvalue = reader.readLine();
   boolean Found = false;
   while(!Found)
      if(Myvalue.toLowerCase().contains(words[0].toLowerCase()))
      {
         Boolean f = false;
         System.out.println("Found"+name);
         update = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE drug_list SET info_link = ? WHERE id = ?;");
         update.setString(1, Myvalue);
         update.setInt(2, id);
         f = update.execute();
         if(!f)
         {
            System.out.println("QSE");
            id++;
            writer.write(Myvalue);
            Found = true;
         }

      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Could Not Find"+name+"\n");
         id++;
         Found = false;
      }
}
```

I am able to match the container links that have to be processed on Single Words. But the problem is

I have a drug names like

- Albuterol (Salbutamol)
- Dorzolamide/Timolol

etc..

And Their Corresponding Links like :

```
 - http://Somelink/**albuterol_salbutamol**.htm
 - http://Somelink/**dorzolamide_timolol**.htm
```

Also there are a few Names in the Database that do not have a corresponding link in the text file, i also want to skip those. I have 1153 Values in total in my database.

Also I have a few drug names like

- Calcium Something
- Calcium Something Something
- Calcium Not Something

So this creates a problem IF i am matching just the word[0] that i split up. Because it will update all the values for Calcium Something Field Only.

Comment: Right now you are iterating over integers, but if someone will change your code and get say a request param into id, you will have SQL-Injcetion vuln, use prepared statemets. Please.

Comment: Well this code is to build my own database, i am not using this code in any application that has to be visible to whole world. So i don't think SQL injection at the moment is what i need to think about.

Comment: @fatfredyy Also I don't think Update Queries can use PreparedStatement Can thay ?

Comment: yes they can, you used one youreself, but I was worried about your select statement. And better be safe than sorry :)

Comment: Well thanks for your info about prepared statements guys, But I need a solution to my problem, rather than making my program secure. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a regex to split the words. Something like

```
String words[] = a.split("[/()]");
```

and iterate over and check all the words instead of just one word.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's just what I would do: Iterate through your names and use split() with a space as the delimiter to get every single word in an array. Then, for each link, get the substring from the last dash until the ".htm" (of course, depending on how your links are set up. you could also skip this step). Then, on that string, check for each item in the name-array if it is contained in the link. Count up an integer value for each match, and save it together with the link, e.g. in an array, HashMap etc. (or just keep the link with the most matches in a variable you can update if you find a link with higher matches). At the end, take the link with the most matches.

Currently, if I see that right, you are already splitting, but you only use the first value of that array.

Of course, that's not fail-safe, but it's the best I can think of. You will have to check the results manually anyway if you want to rule out any errors.